# Fitting a two-layer model to wind profile data in python

Tags: python, model-fitting

I'm trying to fit a model to my dataset of wind profiles, i.e. wind speed values `u(z)` at different altitudes `z`.

The model consists of two parts, which I for now simplified to:

```
u(z) = ust/k * ln(z/z0)     for z < zsl

u(z) = a*z + b              for z > zsl
```

In the logarithmic model, `ust` and `z0` are free parameters  `k` is fixed. `zsl` is the height of the surface layer, which is also not known a priori.

I want to fit this model to my data, and I have already tried different approaches. The best result I'm getting so far is with:

```
def two_layer(z,hsl,ust,z0,a,b):
    return ust/0.4*(np.log(z/z0)) if z<hsl else a*z+b

two_layer = np.vectorize(two_layer)

def two_layer_err(p,z,u):
    return two_layer(z,*p)-u

popt, pcov ,infodict, mesg, ier = optimize.leastsq(two_layer_err,[150.,0.3,0.002,0.1,10.],(wspd_hgt,prof),full_output=1)

# wspd_hgt are my measurements heights and 
# prof are the corresponding wind speed values
```

This gives me reasonable estimates for all parameters, except for `zsl` which is not changed during the fitting procedure. I guess this has to do with the fact that is used as a threshold rather than a function parameter. Is there any way I could let `zsl` be varied during the optimization?

I tried something with numpy.piecewise, but that didn't work very well, perhaps because I don't really understand it very well, or I might be completely off here because it's not suitable for my cause.

For the idea, the wind profile looks like this if the axes are reversed (`z` plotted versus `u`):
[image: Wind profile plot]

Comment: I think your problem is that the function is not continuous in general, so when determining the derivative w.r.t. hsl/zsl you probably get infinity and curve_fit can't handle that. I've noticed such things happening before when adding parameters whose behavior is not 'mathematical' but that make sense from a programming viewpoint. I tried playing around with your problem with a different package but no luck yet. Is there some way to enforce the function to be continous?

Comment: @tBuLi, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately there's no way to do that.. The best I came up with so far is to loop over reasonable values of hsl and fitting the logarithmic function to the points below and the linear function above.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally have a solution for this type of problem, which I came across while answering a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030866/fitting-of-experimental-data-within-two-different-regions/52035987#52035987).

The solution seems to be to implement a constraint saying that `u1 == u2` at the switch between the two models. Because I cannot try it with your model because there is no data posted, I will instead show how it works for the other model, and you can adapt it to your situation. I solved this using a `scipy` wrapper I wrote to make fitting of such problems more pythonic, called `symfit`. But you could do the same using the SLSQP algorithm in `scipy` if you prefer.

```
from symfit import parameters, variables, Fit, Piecewise, exp, Eq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t, y = variables('t, y')
m, c, d, k, t0 = parameters('m, c, d, k, t0')

# Help the fit by bounding the switchpoint between the models
t0.min = 0.6
t0.max = 0.9

# Make a piecewise model
y1 = m * t + c
y2 = d * exp(- k * t)
model = {y: Piecewise((y1, t <= t0), (y2, t > t0))}

# As a constraint, we demand equality between the two models at the point t0
# Substitutes t in the components by t0
constraints = [Eq(y1.subs({t: t0}), y2.subs({t: t0}))]

# Read the data
tdata, ydata = np.genfromtxt('Experimental Data.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1).T

fit = Fit(model, t=tdata, y=ydata, constraints=constraints)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)

plt.scatter(tdata, ydata)
plt.plot(tdata, fit.model(t=tdata, **fit_result.params).y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I think you should be able to adapt this example to your situation!

Edit: as requested in the comment, it is possible to demand matching derivatives as well. In order to do this, the following additional code is needed for the above example:

```
from symfit import Derivative

dy1dt = Derivative(y1, t)
dy2dt = Derivative(y2, t)
constraints = [
    Eq(y1.subs({t: t0}), y2.subs({t: t0})),
    Eq(dy1dt.subs({t: t0}), dy2dt.subs({t: t0}))
]
```

That should do the trick! So from a programming point of view it is very doable, although depending on the model this might not actually have a solution.

Comment: I don't have time to dive into it right now, but would it be possible to add a second constraint stating that the derivatives should match as well?

Comment: @Peter9192 Yes it is, I updated my answer to include this.