# Fitting of experimental data within two different regions

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am fitting a set of experimental data ([sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JOw7bDwWWXSkR_uU2aELrxx33bdqfR1nVci_w1VFUOw/edit?usp=sharing)) within two different experimental regions and can be expressed with two mathematical functions as follows:

**1st region:**

```
y = m*x + c ( the slope can be constrained to zero)
```

**2nd region:**

```
y = d*exp(-k*x)
```

the experimental data is shown below and I coded it in python as follows:

```
def func(x, m, c, d, k):
   return m*x+ c + d*np.exp(-k*x) 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, t, y)
```

Unfortunately, my data is not fitting properly and fitted (returned) parameters do not make sense (see picture below).

Any assistance will be appreciated.

[image: Here is the link to plotted data]

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: In your equation you might need something like "if X < 0,5 use equation_1 else use equation_2" type logic

Comment: Here is the link to the xperimental data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JOw7bDwWWXSkR_uU2aELrxx33bdqfR1nVci_w1VFUOw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very interesting question. As said by a_guest, you will have to fit to the two regions separately. However, I think you probably also want the two regions to connect smoothly at the point `t0`, the point where we switch from one model to the other. In order to do this, we need to add the constraint that `y1 == y2` at the point `t0`.

In order to do this with `scipy`, look at `scipy.optimize.minimize` with the SLSQP method. However, I wrote a `scipy` wrapper to make this kind of thing easier, called `symfit`. I will show you how to do this with `symfit`, because I think it's better suited to the task, but with this example you should also be able to implement it with pure `scipy` if you prefer.

```
from symfit import parameters, variables, Fit, Piecewise, exp, Eq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t, y = variables('t, y')
m, c, d, k, t0 = parameters('m, c, d, k, t0')

# Help the fit by bounding the switchpoint between the models
t0.min = 0.6
t0.max = 0.9

# Make a piecewise model
y1 = m * t + c
y2 = d * exp(- k * t)
model = {y: Piecewise((y1, t <= t0), (y2, t > t0))}

# As a constraint, we demand equality between the two models at the point t0
# to do this, we substitute t -> t0 and demand equality using `Eq`
constraints = [Eq(y1.subs({t: t0}), y2.subs({t: t0}))]

# Read the data
tdata, ydata = np.genfromtxt('Experimental Data.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1).T

fit = Fit(model, t=tdata, y=ydata, constraints=constraints)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)

plt.scatter(tdata, ydata)
plt.plot(tdata, fit.model(t=tdata, **fit_result.params).y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, but could you elaborate a bit more on how the constraint is imposed internally? Are the two domains fitted simultaneously with a compound loss function? Or are the fitted separately and the parameters of the "second" model (probably the right one) are constrained by the result of the first (the left) (or vice versa)?

Comment: @a_guest: Internally we indeed fit to a different loss function. Essentially, we perform a normal least squares fit where the equality constraint is added as a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). This way, the fitting problem is really changed in one where the continuity at the switch-point is guaranteed at every step of the minimization :). I hope this answers you're question, if not let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Since your data shows different behavior in different regions you also need to fit the data on these different regions. That is instead of making a sum of the two models (functions) you should fit one the left region with `y = m*x + c` and separately on the right region with `y = d*exp(-k*x)`. If you have trouble finding the boundary of the two regions you could assess this by comparing the [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit).

```
popt_1, pcov_1 = curve_fit(lambda x, m, c: m*x + c, t[t < 0.8], y[t < 0.8], p0=(1, 0))
popt_2, pcov_2 = curve_fit(lambda x, d, k: d*exp(-k*x), t[t >= 0.8], y[t >= 0.8], p0=(400, 1))
```

## Edit

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=None)
t = df.t.values
y = df.Y.values

boundary = t[y.argmax()]
t1 = t[t < boundary]
y1 = y[t < boundary]
t2 = t[t >= boundary]
y2 = y[t >= boundary]

f1 = lambda x, m, c: m*x + c
f2 = lambda x, d, k: d*np.exp(-k*x)
popt_1 ,pcov_1 = curve_fit(f1, t1, y1, p0=((y1[-1] - y1[0]) / (t1[-1] - t1[0]), y1[0]))
popt_2 ,pcov_2 = curve_fit(f2, t2, y2, p0=(y2[0], 1))

plt.title('Fitted data on two different domains')
plt.xlabel('t [a.u.]')
plt.ylabel('y [a.u.]')
plt.plot(t, y, '-o', label='Data')
plt.plot(t1, f1(t1, *popt_1), '--', color='#ff7f0e', lw=3, label='Fit')
plt.plot(t2, f2(t2, *popt_2), '--', color='#ff7f0e', lw=3, label='_nolegend_')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Data plot]

Note that the resulting "compound" function is not continuous at the boundary. If that is undesired you can resolve it by fixing one the fit parameters (e.g.`k`) before fitting the other domain (one way or the other). Alternatively you could fit both regions separately, then determine the value at the boundary as the average of the two separate functions (i.e. `y_b = (f1(t1[-1], *popt_1) + f2(t2[0], *popt_2)) / 2`) and then repeat the fitting by constraining the parameters such that this boundary condition is fulfilled.

For example fitting the linear function first and then fixing the `d` parameter of the exponential in order to have a continuous transition at the boundary (note that the linear function `f1` is *extrapolated* outside its domain at `t2[0]` in order to ensure the continuity):

```
f1 = lambda x, m, c: m*x + c
popt_1, pcov_1 = curve_fit(f1, t1, y1, p0=((y1[-1] - y1[0]) / (t1[-1] - t1[0]), y1[0]))

d = f1(t2[0], *popt_1)
f2 = lambda x, k: d*np.exp(-k*(x - boundary))
popt_2, pcov_2 = curve_fit(f2, t2, y2, p0=(1,))
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Continuous fit]

Comment: From the image, the boundary is at the maximum "Y" value - if this should always be true, then automatically finding the boundary is trivially simple. It appears to me as if the data to the left of this value is not a straight line.

Comment: @KJ1 I'm not sure how you came to this conclusion but I edited my answer and added a code example which implements the approach. Indeed finding the boundary from `y.argmax()` seems sufficient here however without detailing knowledge about the problem it's still hard to tell (e.g. one could expect a linear  behavior on the domain `[0, 1]`). Although the data in the left domain isn't perfectly linear it does involve a linear trend and anyway that fact doesn't prevent you from just trying to fit a linear model.

Comment: @KJ1 You should specify why exactly this "is not working". For your sample data the approach of a_guest works well in my environment.

Comment: Thanks @a-guest for your input.  based on your approach, the model fit properly. However, the parameter d seems is not correct.It is reporting around 2300. I expected it to be around the same value as "c". The assumption in my model d*exp(-k*t) is that d is the initial value of "y" which is more or like an average value of first segment of the data fitted with y = mx + c.. if m is constrained to zero, it should provide you with  c which should be within the same region as d. see my plotted in the attached link.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/10xFdGyjt_eANCsoE6M0wpn2ih1RE_ykI/view

Comment: @KJ1 The large value of `d` is due to the fact that you chose `d*exp(-k*t)` as a fit function however that function (or better the corresponding domain) "starts" at the boundary which is greater than zero (hence `d` reflects the value that function takes on at `t = 0` which is outside its domain). If you want `d` to reflect the starting value at the domain then you need to ensure that `exp(-k*x) == 1`, i.e. you need to fit the function `d*exp(-k*(t - boundary))` instead (where `boundary == t2[0]`).

Comment: That works perfectly fine... when you fit within the domain (t-boundary)..

Comment: If I require "d" value to match the "c" value. Based on this your comment "Note that the resulting "compound" function is not continuous at the boundary. If that is undesired you can resolve it by fixing one the fit parameters (e.g.k) before fitting the other domain (one way or the other)." how do I go about it?

Comment: @KJ1 See my edited answer. I have the feeling that you want the functions `f1` and `f2` to "match" at the `boundary` (i.e. `t2[0]`) rather than `d` having the same value as `c` (?). If so then you can do this by first fitting the left function and then fixing the corresponding parameter of the right function before fitting it subsequently (as shown above). This can also be done the other way round (i.e. fitting right domain then left) or even fitting both and then fitting again with boundary value fixed for both. I depicted the first case above. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you would prefer to use a single equation, I found that the Hocket-Sherby equation "y = b - (b-a) * exp(-c * (x**d))" seems like an OK fit to your data, yielding an R-squared of 0.99 and RMSE of 11.2 with parameters a =  1.1262189756312683E+01, b =  3.2040596733114870E+02, c =  3.9385197507261771E-01, and d = -4.7723382040098095E+00

[image: modelplot]