# Coupled nonlinear equations python

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I'm having serious troubles with solving translating 3 coupled equations into python.

The 3 equations stem from a 4th order DE used to calculate the bending moment of an underwater pipeline that has been substituted/transformed into 1st order equations and are coupled to each other.

[Latex equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0nv4.png)

The w1, w2 and w3 are three sections of a pipeline that all are derived from integrating the first equation. w1 starts at x=0 and ends at an estimated x= I1, w2 starts at x=I1 and ends at x= I1+I2 and w3 ends at I1+I2+I3.

The system has 15 unknown constraints and 15 boundary constraints conditions for which i want to solve.

**Boundary conditions**

1. w_1(0) = 0 (deflection at x_1 = 0 is 0), *D=0*
2. w_1'(0) = 0 (slope at x_1 = 0 is 0), *C=0*
3. w_1''(0) = 0 (bending moment at x_1 = 0 is 0), *B=0*
4. w_1(I_1) = -p
5. w_2(0) = p, *H=p*
6. w_1'(I_1) = w_2'(0)
7. w_1''(I_1) = w_2''(0)
8. w_2(I_2) = 0
9. w_3(0) = 0
10. w_2'(I_2) = w_3'(0)
11. w_2''(I_2) = w_3''(0)
12. w_2'''(I_2) = w_3'''(0)
13. w_3(I_3) = d
14. w_3(I_3)' = 0
15. w_3(I_3)'' = 0

I've looked online and tried some codes myself, but until now I unfortunately haven't got any useful results. An example of my code is given below, where 15 start / 'guess' values are given for the unknown variables.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import scipy.optimize as opt


#-------------- Pipe and hook plough parameters ------------#
                                                            #
#--------------             PIPE                ------------#    
                                                            #
p = -0.4                                                    # HOOK ELEVATION [m]
d = 1                                                       # BURIAL DEPTH PIPELINE [m]
D_o = 0.324                                                 # OUTSIDE DIAMETER PIPELINE [m]
WT = 0.0254                                                 # WALL THICKNESS PIPELINE [m]
D_i = D_o - 2*WT                                            # INSIDE DIAMETER PIPELINE [m]
A = 0.25*np.pi*(D_o**2 - D_i**2)                            # CROSS SECTIONAL AREA [m]
E_e = 2.1*10**11                                            # YOUNGS MODULUS
sig_max = 413*(10**6)                                       # SYMS
gamma = 1.5                                                 # SAFETY FACTOR Note: 0.67 SYMS
                                                            #
#--------------         ENIVIRONMENT            ------------#  
                                                            #                                                            
g = 9.81                                                    # GRAVITATIONAL ACCELERATION [m/s2]
rho_s = 7840                                                # STEEL DENSITY [kg/m3]
rho_w = 1025                                                # WATER DENSITY [kg/m3]
gamma_wet = 18500                                           # SUBMERGED UNIT WEIGHT SAND [N/m3] Note: North sea soil, fine to medium sand.
gamma_water = 10250                                         # SPECIFIC WEIGHT WATER [N/m3]
phi_g = 37                                                  # HOOK ANGLE TO NEUTRAL [deg] Note: tan(37) = 0.754
K_0 = 0.8                                                   # LATERAL EARTH PRSSURE COEFFICIENT Note: can be between 0.5 an 0.8
                                                            #
#-----------------------------------------------------------#


#-------------- Initialisation calculations     ------------#     

phi_deg= np.tan((phi_g/360)*np.pi*2)                       #         
q_subm = (rho_s*A*g) - (rho_w*np.pi*(D_o/2)**2)*g           # SUBMERGED WEIGHT  [N/m]
q_grnd = D_o*(gamma_wet-gamma_water)*d                      # SOIL WEIGHT [N/m]
q_fric = K_0*phi_deg*(gamma_wet-gamma_water)*(d**2)                     # SOIL FRICTION [N/m]
Q_grnd = q_grnd/d                                           # [N/m]
Q_fric = q_fric/(d**2)                                      # [N/m]
W = (np.pi*(D_o**4 - D_i**4))/(32*D_o)                      # SECTION MODULUS [m3]
I = (np.pi*(D_o**4 - D_i**4))/(64)                          # MOMENT OF INERTIA [m3]
EI = E_e*I                                                  # [Nm2]
M_max = (sig_max*W)/gamma                                   # MAXIMUM ALLAWABLE ELASTIC BENDING MOMENT [Nm]
R_min = EI/M_max                                            # MINIMUM ALLAWABLE ELASTIC RADIUS OF CURVATURE [m]
beta = np.sqrt(np.sqrt((Q_fric+Q_grnd)/(4*EI)))             # SUBSTITUTION FOR IN DIFF EQ. [1/m]                                               
                                                            # 
#-----------------------------------------------------------#


#Test if initialisation calculations are correct                                                            
print('q_subm',q_subm,'\n','q_grnd',q_grnd,'\n','q_fric',q_fric,'\n','Q_grnd',Q_grnd,'\n','Q_fric',Q_fric,'\n','W',W,'\n','I',I,'\n','EI',EI,'\n','M_max',M_max,'\n','R_min',R_min,'\n','beta',beta)            


def main():

    nobservations = 20

    # Guess values for the unkown variables
    I1 = 46.483
    I2 = 5.916
    I3 = 21.90
    A = -3.828*10**(-5)
    B = 0
    C = 0
    D = 0
    E = -1.928*10**(-4)
    F = 4.270*10**(-3)
    G = 0.049
    H = p
    K = 0.052
    L = 0.1
    M = -0.021
    N = 0.787

    f, x1, x2, x3 = generate_data(nobservations, I1, I2, I3, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, K, L, M, N)

    print ('Non-linear results (should be {}, {}, {}):'.format(I1, I2, I3, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, K, L, M, N))
    print (nonlinear_invert(f, x1, x2, x3))

def generate_data(nobservations, I1, I2, I3, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, K, L, M, N, noise_level=0.01):
    x, y, z = np.random.random((3, nobservations))
    noise = noise_level * np.random.normal(0, noise_level, nobservations)
    f = func(x, y, z, I1, I2, I3, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, K, L, M, N) + noise
    return f, x, y, z

def func(x1, x2, x3, I1, I2, I3, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, K, L, M, N):
    f = (A*x1**3 + B*x1**2 + C*x1 + D + (q_subm*x1**4)/(24*EI))

    #I would like to include/couple these two equations   
    f2 = (E*x2**3 + F*x2**2 + G*x2 + H + (q_subm*x2**4)/(24*EI))
    f3 = K*np.exp(np.sqrt(2)*beta*x3)+L*np.exp(-np.sqrt(2)*beta*x3)+M*np.cos(np.sqrt(2)*beta*x3)+N*np.sin(np.sqrt(2)*beta*x3)-(q_subm/(Q_grnd+Q_fric)) 
    return f

def nonlinear_invert(f, x1, x2, x3):
    # "curve_fit" expects the function to take a slightly different form...
    def wrapped_func(observation_points, I1, I2, I3, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, K, L, M, N):
        x1, x2, x3 = observation_points
        return func(x1, x2, x3, I1, I2, I3, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, K, L, M, N)

    xdata = np.vstack([x1, x2, x3])
    model, cov = opt.curve_fit(wrapped_func, xdata, f)
    return model

main()
```

Could anybody please be so kind to assist me?

Comment: Hi Ronald. Please note that LaTeX is (sadly) not enabled on stackoverflow. Maybe you have better luck if you paste your formulas as pics.

Comment: You can use online services like http://latex2png.com/ or others to quickly render those images.

Comment: Done! Added it via picture.

Comment: As the 3 equations have differents domains, you can define a picewise function using different `if` statements over `func`. Also it looks like you're trying to approximate the different parameters by regression, however in `x, y, z = np.random.random((3, nobservations))` what i assume are the spatial variables do not  look like they're appropriately spread over the spatial domain. And the objetive function that you`re trying to fit is very complex, I think it will be easier to numerically integrate the original ODE and then use curve_fit to approximate the unknowns. Hope it helps

Comment: Quick question: in your picture with equations it says 0 <= x_2 <= I_2, but in your text you suggest I_1 <= x_2 <= I_2. I assume you mean the second? Identical question about x_3.

Comment: I think you might be interested in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795341/fitting-a-two-layer-model-to-wind-profile-data-in-python/52036193#52036193) question. It's a much simpler equation than yours, but the principle is the same. You should be able to adapt this example to incorporate all your constraints and conditions.